# How to compare post id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I got the post ids which was posted before 1 day by using the below code.

I have to highlight these post id heading in front page (index.php).

```
$today  = current_time('mysql', 1);
$aa = 1;

if($recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$aa days")) . "' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC")):
  foreach($recentposts as $post) {
     echo $post->ID;
  } 
endif;
```

within the have_post() loop how can check the condition " $post->ID == get_the_ID() " ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [WordPress Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) for the WP-Functions. This will help you to get many information from WP itself (without querying the database directly).

For example you can use the function [get_post($id)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) to get the post data by its ID (if you don't already have the data array) or directly using the [get_the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) function.

EDIT: get_the_ID() is already described above ;)

With get_post() it would be something like this:

```
foreach($recentposts as $post) {
 echo "ID is: ".$post->ID."<br><br>";
 $p = get_post($post->ID);
 print_r($p);
}
```

In the result array you have values with the timestamp (created / updated) and you can easily compare if this values ist "today" eg. by using something like this.

```
if(date("ddmmyy",time()-86400) == date("ddmmyy",$p['created'])){}
```

Comment: I wanna to compare because if 10 posts are display in home page. I need to highlight the heading which was posted before 1 day

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to compare the post id within the loop with some values. If so, you can try the following code

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if (get_the_ID() >value) {
                        ...highlight...
                       }
             }?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if (get_the_ID() >value) here what should i give for value ?

Comment: value => $post[0]->ID - in this case you look for every ID that is "later" then the first one you want to highlight.